# T-Sql 2005 Adding hours to a datetime field with the result within working hours

Tags: sql, t-sql, dateadd

I have two Datetime fields that I wish to add together. They are in the following format: '01/01/1900 00:00:00'.

The main issue with this is that I want the calculation to only include working hours.
The working day is between 08:30 and 17:30 and does not include weekends:

Also if the first field starts out of the working day or is on a weekend then  the second field should be added from the start of the next working day.

For example:

`'26/06/2009 15:45:00' + '01/01/1900 09:00:00' = '29/06/1900 15:45:00'

'12/07/2009 14:22:36' + '01/01/1900 18:00:00' = '13/07/1900 08:30:00'

'15/07/2009 08:50:00' + '01/01/1900 04:00:00' = '15/07/2009 12:50:00'`

Im pretty sure that this is going to involve creating a user defined function to work this out but I have no idea how to even start this(I am quite out of my depth here) Could anyone offer me some advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think your question makes much sense. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to calculate a date+time in the future by adding a certain number of working hours to another date(that may or may not be within working hours).Im not sure How I can clarify it much further if I am honest.

Comment: I think what you are really tring is add JUST the time portion from the second datetime value to the first datetime value. If this is correct, you need to correct your second example. Shouldn't it be '12/07/2009 14:22:36' + '01/01/1900 18:00:00' = '14/07/1900 14:22:00', since you are adding 18 'working' hours?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant '12/07/2009 14:22:36' + '01/01/1900 18:00:00' = '14/07/2009 14:22:00'

Comment: That's not correct as the 12th is a sunday and the first date shouldn't start outside working hours. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, you might have to put it in a function

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME,
        @StartOfDay FLOAT,
        @EndOfDay FLOAT,
        @DateAdd DATETIME

SELECT  @Date ='2009-06-26 15:45:00.000',
        @StartOfDay = 8.5,
        @EndOfDay = 17.5,
        @DateAdd = '1900-01-01 09:00:00.000'

--fix up start date
--before start of day, move to start of day
IF ((CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24) < @StartOfDay)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @StartOfDay * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
END

--after close of day, move to start of next day
IF ((CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24) > @EndOfDay)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @StartOfDay * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1
END

--move to monday if on weekend
WHILE DATENAME(dw, @Date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
BEGIN
    SET @Date = @Date + 1
END

--get the number of hours to add and the total hours per day
DECLARE @HoursPerDay FLOAT
DECLARE @HoursAdd FLOAT
SET @HoursAdd = DATEDIFF(hh, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', @DateAdd)
SET @HoursPerDay = @EndOfDay - @StartOfDay

--date the time of geiven day
DECLARE @CurrentHours FLOAT
SET @CurrentHours = CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24

--if we stay in the same day, all is fine
IF (@CurrentHours + @HoursAdd <= @EndOfDay)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = @Date + @DateAdd
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --remove part of day
    SET @HoursAdd = @HoursAdd - (@EndOfDay - @CurrentHours)
    --,ove to next day
    SET @Date = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1

    --loop day
    WHILE @HoursAdd > 0
    BEGIN
        --add day but keep hours to add same
        IF (DATENAME(dw,@Date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday'))
        BEGIN
            SET @Date = @Date + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --add a day, and reduce hours to add
            IF (@HoursAdd > @HoursPerDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Date = @Date + 1
                SET @HoursAdd = @HoursAdd - @HoursPerDay
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                --add the remainder of the day
                SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, (@HoursAdd + @StartOfDay) * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
                SET @HoursAdd = 0
            END
        END     
    END
END

SELECT @Date
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

you could use the dayofweek function and some in-line case statements;

http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/date-time/dayofweek.html

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php

so, you'd perform the calculation if the dayofweek function didn't return sat. or sun.; else return a null.

I think you could get away without writing a user-defined function, but the sql statement would look a bit messy.  but then again most non-basic sql statements all look a bit messy!

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
This sample down below updating  previous material an shown what's happened if you want to ADD more than 23 hours to a date:
*/


USE [REP]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fct_add_hours_depend_workshift_L-V_0830_1830]    Script Date: 11/26/2018 3:22:37 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*

UTILIZATION

SELECT
GETDATE () as crt_date
,[rep].[dbo].[fct_add_hours_depend_workshift_L-V_0830_1830]
            (
                GETDATE()
                ,number_of_hours_as_integer -- ex: 96
            ) as_expiration_date

ORIGINAL SOURCE:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130721/t-sql-2005-adding-hours-to-a-datetime-field-with-the-result-within-working-hours

*/


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fct_add_hours_depend_workshift_L-V_0830_1830]
(
@Date DATETIME,
@HrsAdd INT
)

RETURNS DATETIME

as

BEGIN

DECLARE @StartOfDay FLOAT,
        @EndOfDay FLOAT

-- workshift declaration de la 8:30 la 18:30
SELECT  @StartOfDay = 8.5,
        @EndOfDay = 18.5


--fix up start date
--before start of day, move to start of day
IF ((CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24) < @StartOfDay)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @StartOfDay * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
END




--after close of day, move to start of next day
IF ((CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24) > @EndOfDay)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @StartOfDay * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1
END

--move to monday if on weekend
WHILE DATENAME(dw, @Date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
BEGIN
    SET @Date = @Date + 1
END

--get the number of hours to add and the total hours per day
DECLARE @HoursPerDay FLOAT
DECLARE @HoursAdd FLOAT
DECLARE @DateAdd DATETIME

/*
Pentru ca scriptul initial nu-ti permite sa adaugi mai mult de 23 ore am facut o modificare:
- daca trebuie sa adaug mai putin de 23 de ore merg pe clasicul definit de dezvoltator
- daca trebuie sa adaug mai mult de 23 ore fac impartirea la 23 cu rest : ex 96 impartit cu rest la 23 = 4 zile (de workshift L-V 8:30-18:30) si 4 ore (de workshift L-V 8:30-18:30) si voi folosi numai intregul sau daca vrei 96/23 si iau  modulo
*/

-- Do I have to add more than 23 hours?

IF (@HrsAdd > 23)
BEGIN

SET @DateAdd = DATEADD
                        (dd,
                        @HrsAdd/23,
                    CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as DATETIME)
                        )
END

ELSE

SET @DateAdd = CAST('1900-01-01 ' + CAST(@HrsAdd as NVARCHAR(2)) + ':00:00.000' as DATETIME)


SET @HoursAdd = DATEDIFF(hh, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', @DateAdd)
SET @HoursPerDay = @EndOfDay - @StartOfDay

--date the time of geiven day
DECLARE @CurrentHours FLOAT
SET @CurrentHours = CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24

--if we stay in the same day, all is fine
IF (@CurrentHours + @HoursAdd <= @EndOfDay)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = @Date + @DateAdd
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --remove part of day
    SET @HoursAdd = @HoursAdd - (@EndOfDay - @CurrentHours)
    --,ove to next day
    SET @Date = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1

    --loop day
    WHILE @HoursAdd > 0
    BEGIN
        --add day but keep hours to add same
        IF (DATENAME(dw,@Date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday'))
        BEGIN
            SET @Date = @Date + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --add a day, and reduce hours to add
            IF (@HoursAdd > @HoursPerDay)
            BEGIN
                SET @Date = @Date + 1
                SET @HoursAdd = @HoursAdd - @HoursPerDay
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                --add the remainder of the day
                SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, (@HoursAdd + @StartOfDay) * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
                SET @HoursAdd = 0
            END
        END     
    END
END
RETURN @Date

END
```