# Adding hours to a datetime field with the result within working hours with lunch time / holidays and extra time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this function below from (Adriaan Stander), but now I need to consider also lunch time / holidays / Extra time.
I have trouble finding a solution. Can anyone help me, what am O doing wrong?

[T-Sql 2005 Adding hours to a datetime field with the result within working hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130721/t-sql-2005-adding-hours-to-a-datetime-field-with-the-result-within-working-hours)

I tried to modified it, but it keeps me send wrong results:

```sql
alter  function [dbo].ufn_getworkhr(@Date DATETIME, @DateAdd DATETIME)
returns datetime
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @StartOfDay FLOAT = 8.5 ;
    DECLARE @EndOfDay FLOAT = 17.5 ;
    DECLARE @StartOfLunch FLOAT = 12.5;
    DECLARE @EndOfLunch FLOAT = 13.5;
    DECLARE @Datefinal DATETIME
    DECLARE @StartDay DATETIME
    DECLARE @ActStartDay DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDay DATETIME
    DECLARE @ActEndDay DATETIME
    DECLARE @cntmin int
--      DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2021-10-06 08:01:00.000';
--      DECLARE @DateAdd DATETIME = '1900-01-02 03:01:00.000'; 
    --  set @DateAdd  = '1900-01-01 09:00:00.000'; 
    --fix up start date
    --before start of day, move to start of day
    IF ((CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24) < @StartOfDay)
    BEGIN  
        SET @ActStartDay=@Date
        -- print 'before start of day, move to start of day'
        SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @StartOfDay * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))  
        SET @StartDay=@Date
        --SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @ActStartDay,@StartDay)  
        SET @cntmin=DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @ActStartDay,@StartDay)  
    END
    
    --after close of day, move to start of next day 
    IF ((CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24) > @EndOfDay)
    BEGIN
        SET @ActEndDay=@Date
        -- print 'after close of day, move to start of next day'
        SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @StartOfDay * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1
        SET @EndDay=@Date
        --SELECT @Date,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@EndDay, @ActEndDay) 
    END
     
    DECLARE @DATA_START1 DATETIME, @DATA_END1 DATETIME,@EXTRA1 INT 
    DECLARE db_cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DATA_START , DATA_END,EXTRA  FROM tbl_workhrs 
    OPEN db_cursor1  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @DATA_START1 , @DATA_END1 ,@EXTRA1 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        IF @EXTRA1=0
        BEGIN  
            IF DATEDIFF(DD,@DATE, @DATA_START1)=0  
            BEGIN 
                SET @Date = @Date + 1
            END
        END  
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @DATA_START1 , @DATA_END1 ,@EXTRA1 
    END 
    CLOSE db_cursor1  
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor1 

    --move to monday if on weekend
    WHILE DATENAME(dw, @Date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
    BEGIN   
        SET @Date = @Date + 1
    END  

    --get the number of hours to add and the total hours per day
    DECLARE @HoursPerDay FLOAT
    DECLARE @HoursAdd FLOAT
    SET @HoursAdd = DATEDIFF(hh, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', @DateAdd)   
    DECLARE @HoursAddmins FLOAT
    SET @HoursAddmins=DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @DateAdd), 0), @DateAdd) 
    
    SET @HoursPerDay = @EndOfDay - @StartOfDay
     
    --date the time of geiven day
    --  select @date
    DECLARE @CurrentHours FLOAT
    SET @CurrentHours = CAST(@Date - DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) AS FLOAT) * 24
    DECLARE @CurrentHoursmin FLOAT
    SET @CurrentHoursmin=DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Date), 0), @Date)
    --if we stay in the same day, all is fine 
    --IF (@CurrentHours + @HoursAdd <= @EndOfDay)
    --select @date
    IF (@CurrentHoursmin + @HoursAddmins <= ((@EndOfDay*60)-60))
    BEGIN    
        -- print 'if we stay in the same day, all is fine'
        -- SET @Date = @Date + @DateAdd  
         
        SET @Date= DATEADD(mi,@HoursAddmins,   @Date);  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN    
        -- print 'remove part of day'
        -- SET @HoursAdd = @HoursAdd - (@EndOfDay - @CurrentHours) 
         
        SET @HoursAddmins = @HoursAddmins - (((@EndOfDay*60) - @CurrentHoursmin)-60)  
        --select @HoursAddmins
        --  move to next day
        SET @Date = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1
    --select @date
        --  loop day
        --WHILE @HoursAdd > 0
        WHILE @HoursAddmins > 0
        BEGIN   
        --  add day but keep hours to add same
            IF (DATENAME(dw,@Date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday'))
            BEGIN
            --  select 123,@date
                IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_workhrs WHERE @DATE BETWEEN DATA_START AND DATA_END AND EXTRA=1)
                BEGIN 
                --select 321
                ---SELECT @DATE
                    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, (@HoursAddmins+(@StartOfDay*60))-60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
                    SET @HoursAddmins = 0   
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                --SELECT 1233
                ---- print '--add day but keep hours to add same'
                    SET @Date = @Date + 1               
                END
                --SET @Date = @Date + 1     
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN    
        --  select 321
            
                DECLARE @DATA_START DATETIME, @DATA_END DATETIME,@EXTRA INT
                --  add a day, and reduce hours to add
                --IF (@HoursAdd > @HoursPerDay)
                DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT DATA_START , DATA_END,EXTRA  FROM tbl_workhrs 
                OPEN db_cursor  
                FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DATA_START , @DATA_END  ,@EXTRA
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                BEGIN  
                    IF @EXTRA=0
                    BEGIN  
                        IF @DATE BETWEEN @DATA_START AND @DATA_END  
                        BEGIN 
                        --SELECT @DATE,1
                            SET @Date = @Date + 1 
                            --SELECT @DATE,2
                        END
                    END  
                    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DATA_START , @DATA_END ,@EXTRA  
                END 
                CLOSE db_cursor  
                DEALLOCATE db_cursor 
                
                IF (@HoursAddmins > (@HoursPerDay*60))
                BEGIN  
                -- select 22,@Date
                    -- print '@HoursAdd > @HoursPerDay'
                    SET @Date = @Date + 1
                    --SET @HoursAdd = @HoursAdd - @HoursPerDay
                    SET @HoursAddmins = @HoursAddmins - (@HoursPerDay*60)
                    -- SET @HoursAddmins =@HoursAddmins -(24*60)
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN       
            --  select 11
                    -- print 'add the remainder of the day'
                    --SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, (@HoursAdd + @StartOfDay) * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
                    --SET @HoursAdd = 0
                    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @HoursAddmins+(@StartOfDay*60), DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
                    SET @HoursAddmins = 0                
                END
            --  print @DAte
            END
        END
    END
     
    --  print 'dsdf'
--  SELECT @date,1234
    IF DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Date), 0), @Date) > (@StartOfLunch*60) 
    BEGIN   
        IF DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Date), 0), @Date) < (@EndOfLunch*60) 
        BEGIN  
            SET @Date= DATEADD(mi, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Date), 0), @Date) - (@StartOfLunch*60))+59,   @Date); 
         
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SET @Date= DATEADD(mi,((@EndOfLunch-@StartOfLunch)*60)+60,   @Date);  
        END     
    END 
    --ELSE
    --BEGIN 
    ----SELECT 13
    --  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_workhrs WHERE @DATE BETWEEN DATA_START AND DATA_END AND EXTRA=0)
    --  BEGIN 
    --      SET @Date= DATEADD(mi,@HoursAddmins+60,   @Date);  
    --  END
    --END   
    
    IF DATEPART(DAY,  @DateAdd)>1
    BEGIN   
        SET @Date=DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(DAY,  @DateAdd)-1, @Date)
    END 
    
    SET @Datefinal = (SELECT @Date)
    --print @Datefinal
    RETURN @Datefinal
    --  select * from tbl_workhrs  
    END
```

Comment: I must admit, that SQL looks *far* from efficient with all those `WHILE` loops and `CURSOR`s. I would suggest a complete rethink, if I am honest. A calender and time table will be invaluable here.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu a calendar table will be invaluable. Together with a table that contains standard working/non-working hours (e.g. shift table), a single query could perform the calculation as a more efficient set-based operation. Search the internet for calendar table and you'll find man examples, including [this one](https://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/).

Comment: Do you mind if I add an answer, which you can treat as pseudo code, but which is implemented with a different database?  I will provide an SQL Server version as well.  But I thought you might want to see how this might be done with a single query expression, avoiding the procedural logic.  This doesn't include any employee/person identifier.  The extra partitioning/grouping can be easily added later.  This includes normal work hours, lunch, etc, and can easily handle `extra` hours and holiday logic.  I didn't want to add too much to the initial SQL.

Comment: i didnt understand the Joe Armstrong idea, can you explain ?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I've created a solution that calculates the total actual work hours, as described by the question, in a `single query expression`, without all the procedural looping logic, cursors, etc.  It's likely to be much more efficient, and even easier to read / write.  Without a function.  But this could certainly be used in a procedure or function.

Comment: Can you share the single query expression ?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Done.  See the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example / result of a test case, for which I have a solution.  I'll post the corresponding SQL shortly.

I didn't adjust `start_time` or the `end_time` to be precise based on the actual hours needed, nor the end of the prior `order`.  That can be tweaked later.

The date ranges are all dynamically determined based on the project start time and the requirements contained in the related orders.

```
+---------+----------+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| proj_id | order_id | hour_est | rsum | start_time          | end_time            | max_hours |
+---------+----------+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|       1 |        1 |     15.5 | 15.5 | 2021-01-11 08:30:00 | 2021-01-12 13:30:00 |   16.0000 |
|       1 |        2 |     10.0 | 25.5 | 2021-01-12 13:30:00 | 2021-01-14 08:30:00 |   28.0000 |
|       1 |        3 |     70.3 | 95.8 | 2021-01-14 08:30:00 | 2021-01-26 13:30:00 |   96.0000 |
+---------+----------+----------+------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

[Fiddle - for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3af6bc05ad09a676d4f2656bb54ebd5)

The fiddle contains step by step panels that show how the single query expression was developed, and the partial results for each step.

For SQL Server, this single query expression creates the test data, calendar, the time sheet hours reported and calculates the effective worked hours based on the normal work hours, plus any extra hours reported with `extra = 1`.

This handles normal work days from Monday through Friday, and hours from 8:30 to 12:30 and 13:30 to 17:30, plus support for `extra` hours reported.

The `extra` hours are assumed to be outside normal work hours / days.  No attempt to resolve overlapping time entries is done.

The resultant hours are reported as a running sum over the days within the test calendar, ordered by start date/time.

I'll add more detailed description of the CTE terms shortly.

This is just an example of how this might be done without procedural logic, cursors and explicit looping.

The actual logic to calculate worked hours is done starting with the `xoverlap` CTE term.  Prior to that is just setup of the test data.

Adding logic to support multiple employees/workers would be trivial.  That's just a matter of using appropriate `PARTITION BY` logic.

Adding support for holidays would also be fairly simple.

**Document the CTE terms:**

| N | CTE term | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1) | `drange` | The date range of the test calendar (to be generated) |
| 2) | `dates0` | Recursively generate the dates in this test calendar |
| 3) | `dates` | Remove the weekend days from the normal work calendar |
| 4) | `hours` | Specify the minute ranges in the day representing normal work hours |
| 5) | `datehours` | Join the normal work hours with each date in the test calendar |
| 6) | `tbl_workhrs` | Add the reported time worked for this employee, including `extra` time |
| 7) | `xoverlap` | Handle the overlap logic between reported time and calendar hours, plus support for `extra` |
| 8) | `totalhrs` | Calculate the running SUM of total hours worked, based on normal and extra time reported |

```
WITH drange (date_start, date_end) AS (      
         SELECT CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE) AS date_start, CAST('2021-02-01' AS DATE) AS date_end
     )
   , dates0 (adate, date_end) AS (                     
         SELECT date_start, date_end FROM drange UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(day,  1, adate), date_end
           FROM dates0
          WHERE adate < date_end
     )
   , dates (adate) AS (                                
         SELECT adate FROM dates0 WHERE DATENAME(dw , adate) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
     )
   , hours (hour_start, hour_end) AS (                 
         SELECT  8.5*60, 12.5*60 UNION
         SELECT 13.5*60, 17.5*60
     )
   , datehours (xstart, xend) AS (                     
         SELECT DATEADD(minute, hour_start, CAST(adate AS datetime))
              , DATEADD(minute, hour_end  , CAST(adate AS datetime))
           FROM dates AS d, hours AS h
     )
   , tbl_workhrs (start_datetime, end_datetime, extra) AS (  
         SELECT CAST('2021-01-11 07:00' AS datetime), CAST('2021-01-12 10:00' AS datetime), 0 UNION
         SELECT CAST('2021-01-15 13:00' AS datetime), CAST('2021-01-18 20:00' AS datetime), 0 UNION   
         SELECT CAST('2021-01-20 20:00' AS datetime), CAST('2021-01-20 22:00' AS datetime), 1
     )
   , xoverlap AS (                     
         SELECT CASE WHEN dh.xstart >= wk.start_datetime THEN dh.xstart ELSE wk.start_datetime END AS xstart
              , CASE WHEN dh.xend   <= wk.end_datetime   THEN dh.xend   ELSE wk.end_datetime   END AS xend
              , wk.*
           FROM tbl_workhrs AS wk
           JOIN datehours   AS dh
             ON dh.xstart < wk.end_datetime AND dh.xend > wk.start_datetime
          WHERE wk.extra = 0
          UNION
         SELECT wk.start_datetime, wk.end_datetime, wk.start_datetime, wk.end_datetime, wk.extra
           FROM tbl_workhrs AS wk
           JOIN drange      AS dr
             ON wk.extra = 1 AND wk.start_datetime < dr.date_end AND wk.end_datetime > dr.date_start
     )
   , totalhrs AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, xstart, xend)) OVER (ORDER BY xstart) / 60.0 AS hours
           FROM xoverlap AS t
     )
SELECT * FROM totalhrs
 ORDER BY xstart
;
```

**The result:**

[image]

Assuming the data, calendar, tbl_workhrs, etc were stored in the database, the following would be all we need, essentially:

```
WITH xoverlap AS (                     
         SELECT CASE WHEN dh.xstart >= wk.start_datetime THEN dh.xstart ELSE wk.start_datetime END AS xstart
              , CASE WHEN dh.xend   <= wk.end_datetime   THEN dh.xend   ELSE wk.end_datetime   END AS xend
              , wk.*
           FROM tbl_workhrs AS wk
           JOIN datehours   AS dh
             ON dh.xstart < wk.end_datetime AND dh.xend > wk.start_datetime
          WHERE wk.extra = 0
          UNION
         SELECT wk.start_datetime, wk.end_datetime, wk.start_datetime, wk.end_datetime, wk.extra
           FROM tbl_workhrs AS wk
           JOIN drange      AS dr
             ON wk.extra = 1 AND wk.start_datetime < dr.date_end AND wk.end_datetime > dr.date_start
     )
   , totalhrs AS (
         SELECT t.*
              , SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, xstart, xend)) OVER (ORDER BY xstart) / 60.0 AS hours
           FROM xoverlap AS t
     )
SELECT * FROM totalhrs
 ORDER BY xstart
;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. It helped me a lot.

But in my case as a start date I want to add time (let's imagine 18:40).

It's different, because at the start I won't know how many days the company will need for the drange, (let's imagine the company is on vacation for 3 weeks) I'll have to add it day by day until the total time is reached

In that case I won't need a loop?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Correct.  No explicit loop is required.  I don't know what point you're trying to make with the `18:40` comment.  Nothing in my example stops you from trying to aggregate over some specific date/time range.  My example is just that, a hint at how this can all be done.  It's very easy to adjust the logic, add support for holidays or vacation.  Very trivial.  If you would like to clarify your requirement, or provide an explicit test case, I can easily tailor the answer to those details.  Notice how my example contained very specific design detail.  Do the same in your question.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Maybe you misunderstood.  The start/end date at the top of the query was just to generate an initial calendar for the test case.  All the employee time entries were based on complete dates/times. The calendar range was almost immaterial.  But I needed some range to express the test case.   I could have generated the calendar based on the entered employee work entries too.  This is all adjustable.  This could all be parameterized via prepared statement.

Comment: Can you resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of orders each with the amount of time needed to complete it.

The orders table is very simple, it only has the :

Order num - Time _needed - Date_Start - Date_end

Order1 - 23h:15m - ....... - .......

Order2 - 2h:01m - ....... - .......

Order3 - 16h:45m - ....... - .......

Order4 - 18h:35m - ....... - .......

Order5 - 46h:05m - ....... - .......

With the function (based on the company's working time - holidays -holidays + extras) I can fill the date_start and data_end.

When I have the date_start and date_end fill I create a timeline.

And when the company add new extra time to the calendar, i can exec the function and have all the orders update.

I created a function based on ( [T-Sql 2005 Adding hours to a datetime field with the result within working hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130721/t-sql-2005-adding-hours-to-a-datetime-field-with-the-result-within-working-hours))
which works well, but which had its limitations (it did not include holidays, vacations, lunchtime or overtime)

I simply, if I wanted to know when order #1 ended in order to start order #2, I would execute the function:

```
set @date_start='2021-10-06 08:00:00.000' ;
set @time_add = '1900-01-01 01:01:00.000' ;
set @result = (Select dbo.ufn_getworkhr (@date_start , @time_add) )
```

and thus had an answer of the end date of Order No. 1 and therefore the beginning of Order No. 2

performed the function and knew when Order No. 2 ended and Order No. 3 began ...... and so on

The problem is that the dates that were generating me did not include holidays, vacations, lunchtime or overtime, which resulted in poor planning.

With your example I realized that I could really leave the function I have and create a new one, but the example you showed is good but I'm not able to fit my need.

Can you make an example?

Thanks

Comment: That helps.  Can you please add this `orders` table to the question?  It helps to be explicit.

Comment: Doesn't `tbl_workhrs` contain the `orders`?  If not, what does that table represent?  Maybe you should just show your full test case, instead of a link to a problem which doesn't really reflect your requirement.

Comment: The orders table is very simple, it only has the :
Order num - Time _needed - Date_Start - Date_end
Order1 - 23h:15m - ....... - .......
Order2 - 2h:01m - ....... - .......
Order3 - 16h:45m - ....... - .......
Order4 - 18h:35m - ....... - .......
Order5 - 46h:05m - ....... - .......


With the function (based on the company's working time - holidays -holidays + extras) I can fill the date_start and data_end.

Comment: If the company adds new extra time to the calendar I can execute the function and  update the table order with the new time star and time end

Comment: Also I can say that order n4 will start at specific date and time  and I can re calculate all the follow order to the new update time

Comment: Understood.  I have a tentative solution for the basic requirement, without the forced start time of an order or extra time.  Both are easy to add.  I'll post the result of a simple test case.  The SQL needs to be cleaned up before posting that.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Do you have solution  ?

Answer (score 0):

I try to resolve and until now I have the start day fix, now I need to add the time to the date.

I am aware that the query is a little chunky so I asked what could be improved and how can I make a routine to add the time in the following days.

What do you think I could do better ( right now I'm not worried about performance but about getting the function working.

```
--select * from Calendar
--Select * from CalendarShift
--Select * from Calendar (nolock) left join CalendarShift (nolock) on Calendar.shift = CalendarShift.id where cast(CalendarDate AS date) =   (CAST(@Date AS date) )


    DECLARE @Date  DATETIME = '2021-10-28 18:05:00.000';
    DECLARE @DateAdd DATETIME = '1900-01-01 02:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @Date_Int  FLOAT = (select cast(datepart(hour,@Date) + (datepart(minute,@Date)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
    DECLARE @DateAdd_Int FLOAT = (select cast(datepart(hour,@DateAdd) + (datepart(minute,@DateAdd)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
    
    DECLARE @time1_start DATETIME =  '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    DECLARE @time1_end DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'; 
    DECLARE @time2_start DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @time2_end DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @time3_start DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @time3_end DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @time1_start_Int FLOAT =  0 ;
    DECLARE @time1_end_Int FLOAT = 0 ;
    DECLARE @time2_start_Int FLOAT = 0;
    DECLARE @time2_end_Int FLOAT = 0;
    DECLARE @time3_start_Int FLOAT = 0;
    DECLARE @time3_end_Int FLOAT = 0;



--Check working periods from the day
SELECT @time1_start=time1_start,@time1_end=time1_end,@time2_start=time2_start,@time2_end=time2_end,@time3_start=time3_start,@time3_end=time3_end  
FROM Calendar (nolock)  left join CalendarShift (nolock) on Calendar.shift = CalendarShift.id 
WHERE cast(CalendarDate AS date) =   (CAST(@Date AS date))  

--Convert time HH:MM  to decimal
SET @time1_start_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time1_start) + (datepart(minute,@time1_start)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
SET @time1_end_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time1_end) + (datepart(minute,@time1_end)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
SET @time2_start_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time2_start) + (datepart(minute,@time2_start)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
SET @time2_end_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time2_end) + (datepart(minute,@time2_end)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
SET @time3_start_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time3_start) + (datepart(minute,@time3_start)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
SET @time3_end_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time3_end) + (datepart(minute,@time3_end)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )

--Select @Date_Int,@DateAdd_Int,@time1_start_Int,@time1_end_Int,@time2_start_Int,@time2_end_Int,@time3_start_Int,@time3_end_Int


--fix up start date
--before start of day, move to start of day
IF (@Date_Int < @time1_start_Int)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @time1_start_Int * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
    SET @Date_Int = @time1_start_Int
    Select  @Date,@Date_Int
END

--between shift 1 and 2 (lunch time)
IF (@Date_Int > @time1_end_Int and @Date_Int < @time2_start_Int)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @time2_start_Int * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
    SET @Date_Int = @time2_start_Int
    Select  @Date,@Date_Int
END

--between shift 2 and 3 (dinner time)  - --- if exists
IF (@Date_Int > @time2_end_Int and @Date_Int < @time3_start_Int)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @time3_start_Int * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date))
    SET @Date_Int = @time3_start_Int
    Select  @Date,@Date_Int
END


--after close of working day, move to start of next day at 00HH:01M
IF (@Date_Int > @time3_end_Int)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = DATEADD(mi, @time1_start_Int * 60, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@Date)) + 1    
            ----Is missing change the date to YYYY-MM-DD 00:01:00.000
    SET @Date_Int = '0.1'
    Select  @Date,@Date_Int
END


--move to next day  if there is no work (holidays, vacations , sundays saturdays without extra time)
WHILE (@time1_start_Int is null )
BEGIN
    SET @Date = @Date + 1 
            ----Is missing change the date to YYYY-MM-DD 00:01:00.000
    SET @Date_Int = '0.1'
    --Select  @Date,@Date_Int
        SELECT @time1_start=time1_start,@time1_end=time1_end,@time2_start=time2_start,@time2_end=time2_end,@time3_start=time3_start,@time3_end=time3_end  
        FROM Calendar (nolock)  left join CalendarShift (nolock) on Calendar.shift = CalendarShift.id 
        WHERE cast(CalendarDate AS date) =   (CAST(@Date AS date))  

        --Convert time HH:MM  to decimal
            SET @time1_start_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time1_start) + (datepart(minute,@time1_start)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
            SET @time1_end_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time1_end) + (datepart(minute,@time1_end)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
            SET @time2_start_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time2_start) + (datepart(minute,@time2_start)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
            SET @time2_end_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time2_end) + (datepart(minute,@time2_end)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
            SET @time3_start_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time3_start) + (datepart(minute,@time3_start)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )
            SET @time3_end_Int = (select cast(datepart(hour,@time3_end) + (datepart(minute,@time3_end)/60.) as dec(4,2)) )

END



Select @Date,@Date_Int,@DateAdd_Int,@time1_start_Int,@time1_end_Int,@time2_start_Int,@time2_end_Int,@time3_start_Int,@time3_end_Int
```

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Calendar]    Script Date: 09/10/2021 15:58:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [CalendarDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CalendarYear] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CalendarMonth] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CalendarDay] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DayOfWeekName] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FirstDateOfWeek] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDateOfWeek] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDateOfMonth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDateOfMonth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDateOfQuarter] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDateOfQuarter] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDateOfYear] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDateOfYear] [date] NOT NULL,
    [BusinessDay] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [NonBusinessDay] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Weekend] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Holiday] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Weekday] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CalendarDateDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [shift] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CalendarDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CalendarShift]    Script Date: 09/10/2021 15:58:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalendarShift](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [time1_start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [time1_end] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [time2_start] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [time2_end] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [time3_start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [time3_end] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 1, N'Friday', CAST(0x0A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x10430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x10430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 2, N'Saturday', CAST(0x0A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x10430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(2 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 3, N'Sunday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(0 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x12430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 4, N'Monday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x13430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 5, N'Tuesday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x14430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 6, N'Wednesday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x15430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 7, N'Thursday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x16430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 8, N'Friday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 9, N'Saturday', CAST(0x11430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x17430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(2 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 10, N'Sunday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(0 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x19430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 11, N'Monday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, N'Columbus Day', CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x1A430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 12, N'Tuesday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x1B430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 13, N'Wednesday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x1C430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 14, N'Thursday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x1D430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 15, N'Friday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 16, N'Saturday', CAST(0x18430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x1E430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(2 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 17, N'Sunday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(0 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x20430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 18, N'Monday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x21430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 19, N'Tuesday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x22430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 20, N'Wednesday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x23430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 21, N'Thursday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x24430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 22, N'Friday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 23, N'Saturday', CAST(0x1F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(2 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 24, N'Sunday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(0 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x27430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 25, N'Monday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x28430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 26, N'Tuesday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x29430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 27, N'Wednesday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x2A430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 28, N'Thursday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x2B430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 29, N'Friday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, CAST(1 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 30, N'Saturday', CAST(0x26430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2C430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(2 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Calendar] ([CalendarDate], [CalendarYear], [CalendarMonth], [CalendarDay], [DayOfWeekName], [FirstDateOfWeek], [LastDateOfWeek], [FirstDateOfMonth], [LastDateOfMonth], [FirstDateOfQuarter], [LastDateOfQuarter], [FirstDateOfYear], [LastDateOfYear], [BusinessDay], [NonBusinessDay], [Weekend], [Holiday], [Weekday], [CalendarDateDescription], [shift]) VALUES (CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), 2021, 10, 31, N'Sunday', CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x33430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x2D430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x0F430B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), CAST(0xFE410B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6A430B00 AS Date), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, CAST(0 AS Numeric(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CalendarShift] ([id], [name], [time1_start], [time1_end], [time2_start], [time2_end], [time3_start], [time3_end]) VALUES (1, N'Businnes Day', CAST(0x00000000008C1360 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000000000CDFE60 AS DateTime), CAST(0x07007CDB27715B950A AS DateTime2), CAST(0x07001CEDAE925B950A AS DateTime2), CAST(0x0000000000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000000000000000 AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[CalendarShift] ([id], [name], [time1_start], [time1_end], [time2_start], [time2_end], [time3_start], [time3_end]) VALUES (2, N'Extra saturday 4h', CAST(0x000000000083D600 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000000000D63BC0 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0700000000005B950A AS DateTime2), CAST(0x0700000000005B950A AS DateTime2), CAST(0x0000000000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000000000000000 AS DateTime))
GO
```